# Simple function explanation

Tags: javascript

Why does this function alert 10?

```
function b (x, y, a) {
  arguments[2] = 10;
  alert(a);
}

b(1, 2, 3);
```

Comment: It isn't *returning* anything.

Comment: I don't do much javascript, but a Google for "javascript arguments" gave me a good result as the very first result

Comment: I thought that arguments is just another array :(

Comment: @user1612293 Well I didn't know either for a start, just saying it was a pretty easy Google search, so I've learnt something new too :-)

Comment: `arguments` is an object, that resembles an array, but it isn't an array (it has a `length` property, but doesn't have the `slice` method, for example... it also has the `callee` property - which you musn't use)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

javascript arrays are zero indexed and arguments refers to parameters passed into function as arguments :

```
arguments[2] === a === 10
```

and

```
1 === x === arguments[0];
2 === y == arguments[1];
```

(and [triple equality](https://stackoverflow.com/a/523647/106261) operator is not a mistake)

Comment: Perhaps worth mentioning: it's not a very good idea to change the `arguments` object directly. Perhaps use `var writeableArgs = Array.prototype.slice(arguments,[0]);`, and use the returned array instead

Answer (score 4):

Because you're setting the third argument to 10. From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments):

> You can refer to a function's arguments within the function by using
>   the arguments object. This object contains an entry for each argument
>   passed to the function, the first entry's index starting at 0. For
>   example, if a function is passed three arguments, you can refer to the
>   argument as follows:
>
> ```
> arguments[0]
> arguments[1]
> arguments[2]
> ```

Answer (score 3):

The arguments object is a local variable available within all functions; arguments as a property of Function can no longer be used

use this reference for further

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments

Answer (score 1):

This function takes three inputs, discards the first two and displays the last in a modal popup, but not before assigning value `10` to index `2` of `arguments` - effectively setting the input `a` to `10` from `3` - it then exits scope without returning anything at all.